# RXJava - concat doesn't works

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reactive

I've a problem using RXJava and Kotlin.

I'm using LiveData and Rx, my problem is that concat method is not concatenating two arrays that I have in Dummy data.

**This is my code:**

```
 disposables.
                add(
                Observable.concat(Observable.just(DummyContent.COMPANIES),
                        Observable.just(DummyContent.COMPANIES))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    Timber.d("get companies success ${it.size}" )
                    companiesLiveData.value = it
                },{
                     t -> Timber.e(t, "get companies error")
                }))
```

DummyContent:

```
 val COMPANIES: MutableList<Company> = ArrayList()
  ...
   // Add some sample items.
        for (i in 1..4) {
            addCompany(createDummyCompany(i))
        }
```

When I run the code, I only see 4 elements in the list, I was expecting to receive 4  +  4  = 8 items because the `concat` method.

In the LogCat I see this message twice:  get companies success 4

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Observable.concat()` concatenates the two stream given to it. Thus you'll receive two events with the single list. If you want to merge the lists itself, you'd have to emit the single elements instead of the list and make the elements a list again.

```
Observable.concat(Observable.fromIterable(DummyContent.COMPANIES),
                  Observable.fromIterable(DummyContent.COMPANIES))
          .toList()
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, could you tell me the difference between : Observable.fromIterable and Observable.just , both don't return the same?

Comment: The first emits each element of the iterable, the second emits the iterable itself.